# How to sort a HashMap<String, Integer[]>?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a HashMap with a String and an array of Integer and I want to sort the map by the first value of the array.

For example, in the entries:

```
{"Name1"=[2,4],
 "Name2"=[1,5],
 "Name3"=[3]}
```

the order should be:

```
{"Name2"=[1,5],
 "Name1"=[2,4],
 "Name3"=[3]}
```

Comment: if first value of array map is same than ?

Comment: Technically, you can't sort a `HashMap`, but you can use another `Map` class to sort the content of your `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to sort the map by the **first value** of the array

We can use a custom comparator in the stream extracted from the `Map.entrySet()` which takes into consideration the **first element** of the array from the value of the Map when doing the comparison:

```
 Map<String, Integer[]> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("Name1", new Integer[]{2,5});
 map.put("Name2", new Integer[]{1,4});
 map.put("Name3", new Integer[]{3});


 Map<String, Integer[]> sorted = map
                             .entrySet().stream()
                             .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ent -> ent.getValue()[0]))
                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                                      Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                      (a, b) -> b,                                                        
                                                     LinkedHashMap::new));

 sorted.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("{ " + k + " " + Arrays.toString(v) + " }"));
```

Output:

```
{ Name2 [1, 4] }
{ Name1 [2, 5] }
{ Name3 [3] }
```